# Violation of Primary Key - SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm copying a data view (`_unsubscribe`) to a standard data extension so I can view it and manipulate it for our preference center.

It a simple query but I'm getting a violation of primary key error.  Unsure why this would be the case since the `subscriberkey` is the primary key and should be entirely unique.  It's an update query.

```
SELECT *
FROM _unsubscribe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscriber can unsubscribe from any individual list, publication list, suppression list, and All Subscribers. So there are many scenarios where a single subscriber key would appear multiple times on the '_Unsubscribe' data view, which is why the data view doesn't have a primary key.

You could either not use a primary key and simply append on each run of the query, or you could create a compound primary key such as 'Subscriber Key + ListID + EventDate".

If you're looking to reference something for a preference center, you would probably be better off reference the '_Subscribers' or '_ListSubscribers' data views - '_Unsubscribe' is more for tracking individual unsubscribe events.

Comment: Layer on complication is this: we don’t use publication lists or other lists.

Comment: Could be from an unsubscribe --> resubscribe --> unsubscribe scenario perhaps? That would be recorded twice with different dates, potentially leading to the error.

Comment: Interesting.  That could be it.  I'll tool around with it.